# When is the appropriate to use ion-pane?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

This is a simple enough question.

After taking a look at the [documentation for ion-pane](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionPane/) it states:

> A simple container that fits content, with no side effects. Adds the ‘pane’ class to the element.

What does it mean when it states "no side effects"? What are the use cases for ion-pane?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Honestly, I never used ion-pane before, but this question intrigued me so I went searching. As it seems, and you can see on this Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JGwJKv?editors=1010, if the content is too big (if you try to resize the browser window to very small) it will not show it. Opposed to the `ion-content` which will add scroll bars and allow you to use `ion-refresher` and some other options (tapping into scroll delegate, etc.).

So, to be honest, I never stumbled upon a need for such a use-case, so would probably never use ion-pane. The lacking documentation about it, kind of suggests the same...

Comment: Would you look at that. That's interesting, So I guess another way to say that is that ion-pane removes the ionic directive properties of a section. Nice to know thanks for taking the time. Also I tweaked it a little http://codepen.io/garrettmac/pen/OMrKPX. Yours had a ion-pane opening tag and a ion-content closing tag. Thanks again.

Comment: @qizzacious you're welcome. I'm glad this helped, good luck with your project!

Answer (score 1):

I actually used it for the first time on an app where I had dynamic divs that needed to fill the screen without adding scroll bars. Switching from `ion-content` to `ion-pane` did the trick for me.